# How to solve the error "operation time out" in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to print the output of an url ("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=love") in python2.7. This is my code:

```
import urllib

def check_profanity():
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=love")
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

check_profanity()
```

but I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mading/Desktop/python/Udacity/check_profanity.py", line 18, in <module>
    check_profanity()
  File "/Users/mading/Desktop/python/Udacity/check_profanity.py", line 12, in check_profanity
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=love")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 821, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: Well you obviously have connection issues since I get "false" just fine

Comment: But I can visit this url in web browser.